# Sql query group_concat with join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, concatenation

I am trying to join three tables with one query on the bases of Int = Json
Problem is, query showing only one record and ignoring another due to group_concat

```
SELECT tour_package.id, tour_package.description AS description,
       tour_package.NAME AS name,
       Group_concat(DISTINCT(destination_continent.NAME)) AS continent_name,
       Group_concat(DISTINCT(travel_style.NAME)) AS travel_style_name,
       tour_package.img_path_thumb AS img_path_thumb
FROM tour_package
LEFT JOIN destination_continent 
    ON Find_in_set(destination_continent.id, Replace( Replace( Replace( tour_package.continent_id, '\[', '' ) , '\]', '' ) , '"', '' ) )
LEFT JOIN travel_style
    ON Find_in_set( travel_style.id, Replace( Replace( Replace( tour_package.travel_style_id, '\[', '' ) , '\]', '' ) , '"', '' ) )
WHERE `tour_package`.`DELETE` = 0 
       && `destination_continent`.`DELETE` = 0
       && `travel_style`.`DELETE` = 0
```

I am not so good in sql, i know this is not the proper way, using foreign key is the proper solution for that, any way i am taking this as a learning.

Any one plz share if u have any idea

[image: Db record image]

[image: DB query image]

Comment: I cannot read those tiny images on my phone so unable me to offer any insight into your joins.

Answer (score 0):

Quite apart from the inefficient joins you have used, add a group by clause such as this

```
 GROUP BY
    tour_package.id
  , tour_package.description
  , tour_package.NAME
  , tour_package.img_path_thumb
```

This c lause will define the unique attributes of each row.